# How to tell if fgets(stdin) will block on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, io, console-application

How can I tell if the next call to `fgets(stdin, ...)` will block or not? In other words, how can I tell if the `stdin` buffer has a newline waiting to be read?

On Unix, I know I can use `select()` like this:

```
    fd_set reads;
    FD_ZERO(&reads);
    FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &reads);
    int s = select(fileno(stdin)+1, &reads, 0, 0, 0);
    if (s) {
        //fgets is ready
    }
```

However, `select()` on Windows only works with sockets, not with 'stdin', so I cannot use it.

I also know on Unix that I can use `poll()`, `ioctl(0, I_NREAD...)`, and probably a lot of other solutions. None of these work on Windows.

I have tried `kbhit()` and `WaitForSingleObject(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ))`. The problem is that both of these indicate that input is available as soon as the first key is struck. I need to know if a whole line is available, because `fgets()` blocks for an entire line.

Perhaps my issue is that Unix shells tend to buffer entire input lines, while Windows doesn't?

Should I just use `fgetc()` to build up a buffer until I see a newline?

I've done research finding other answers, but none of them work for me. They either use C++, whereas I need a C solution. Or they are focusing on using `fgets()` with sockets, where I need to use it with `stdin`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: On Linux, learn to prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to the old [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)... BTW, `fileno(stdin)` could be replaced by `STDIN_FILENO` which happens to be 0. Also, in pathological cases `select` or `poll` will tell you that stdin is readable, but `fgets` could still block

Comment: Consider using [GNU readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) on Linux. It has been ported to Windows in [Readline-GW](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I'm really trying to do this on Windows. I can't pull in a dependency either, but I'll keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: Since [Readline-GW](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm) is free software, you can study its source code

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell if the next call to `fgets(stdin, ...)` will block or not? In other words, how can I tell if the `stdin` buffer has a newline waiting to be read?

Generally speaking, you cannot tell.  Not on POSIX systems, either, without making some assumptions.  Both POSIX and the Windows API define mechanisms for determining whether input is available, but that's not enough for you.  You want to determine whether specific data (i.e. a line terminator) are available to be read, and the only way C defines for doing that is to read the data.

Therefore, if you really need to read a line at a time without blocking your main thread, then I suggest performing your reads asynchronously.  You could roll your own, with a reader thread separate from your main one, but you might find that [Microsoft's existing asynchronous I/O API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o) supports your needs.